# Assembly x86 imul misunderstanding

Tags: assembly, x86

What is the value of the Overflow flag after the following instructions?

```
.data
word1 SWORD 4
dword1 SDWORD 4
.code
imul bx,word1,-16
imul ebx,dword1,-16
imul ebx,dword1,-2000000000
```

I am having trouble following this question, I know it involves sign extension and overflow of the operand registers into the added sign extended space

Comment: Show what you think, then we can say if it's correct. Be sure to consult an instruction set reference and possibly run the code in a debugger.

Comment: By the way, you will need to know the initial value of `bx`.

Comment: @Jester: No - those instructions are like "bx = rm16 * imm8"

Comment: @Brendan Oh yeah. Good catch. My brain automatically processed the `word1` as a size specifier, eh

Comment: What's stopping you from just trying it?  Then you could at least ask for help understanding the ISA manual's wording (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul) for why it is or isn't set, but this is just appears lazy.